# How can I INSERT multiple rows into a table using PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to `INSERT INTO` two different tables with two different `INSERT` statements. The first one works fine and the second one works as well, however, there can several rows to `INSERT INTO` the second table but this only inserts one row. I thought a `for` loop would work but it doesn't give me what I need.

```
$productID = $_POST['product_id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$productQty = $_POST['qty'];

if(empty($hNum) || empty($street) || empty($city) || empty($county) || empty($postcode) || empty($country)){
  header("Location: checkout.php?error=emptyaddressfields");
  exit();
}
else {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, order_date, order_status, num_items, total_cost)
              VALUES ('$customer_id', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Order Placed', '$num_items', '$total_cost')";

  if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    for($i=0; $i < $productQty; $i++) {
      $sqlOI = "INSERT INTO order_item (order_id, product_id, title, quantity)
                VALUES (
                  (SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders),
                  '$productID',
                  '$title',
                  '$productQty'
                  )";
    }
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlOI)){
      header("Location: account.php?success=orderPlaced");
      exit();
    } 
    else {
      echo "Something went wrong...".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
  }
}
```

If there is a different kind of loop that would work better, please let me know. I have searched online for different ways to do this but either they don't make sense or don't work. If I run the second `INSERT` statement in command line (with out the variables) it works so I know the problem isn't the `SQL`.

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**:
Data is displayed inside a table, and a new row is added when another product has been added to the session array.
Each row in the HTML table is generated by a product being added to the "cart". Each row has the same `<tr>` `<td>` and `<input>` attributes. So when another product is added, it generates a new row, with the same `name="id"` or whatever the name is.

```
<?php
   if(!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])):
     $total = 0;
     $cart_qty = 0;
     foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product):

     <tr>
      <td hidden><input type="text" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>"></td>
       <td>£<?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
       <td>£<?php echo number_format($product['quantity'] * $product['price'], 2); ?></td>
     </tr>

     $total = $total + ($product['quantity'] * $product['price']);
     $cart_qty = $cart_qty + ($product['quantity']);
   endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Maybe check twice what you're doing in the "for" loop.

Comment: It's my understanding that this would loop through each row and run the `INSERT` query each time it found a row. Is that not the case?

Comment: Fetching the order_id in your way is not the right way to do it. https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: For you insert Statement please have a look at prepared statements... https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for better security

Comment: you are only executing the query once

Comment: @rené I know that MAX(id) could cause some issues if another order is placed at the same time, but I'm not too worried about that right now. Do I need to use prepared statements to get this to work? Surely it's just a matter of looping through the shopping cart to find all the rows and insert each row separately?

Comment: Look what’s inside the for loop. The execution is *outside* the loop, so not every loop executes the insert.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: I added `$conn->query($sqlOI);` inside the for loop and now it inserts the correct amount of rows, but the data of each row is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i < $productQty; $i++) {
      $sqlOI = "INSERT INTO order_item (order_id, product_id, title, quantity)
                VALUES (
                  (SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders),
                  '$productID',
                  '$title',
                  '$productQty'
                  )";
    }//bottom of for loop
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlOI)){//execution
      header("Location: account.php?success=orderPlaced");
      exit();
    }
```

You only execute the final loop because you overwrite your sql string each time.
At the very least you should move the execute inside the for loop, but in reality you should probably do something like

```
$sql = [];//create an empty array

    for($i=0; $i < $productQty; $i++) {
//insert a  an update row
$sql[] = "VALUES ((SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders),:pdo_placeholder" . $I . ",.....)"
        }

//implode the rows into a final string then do the connection
 $sql = "INSERT INTO order_item 
(order_id, product_id, title, quantity) VALUES " .  implode(',',$sql);



//now we are outside the loop we can execute
//lets assume you've changed this to a properly prepared pdo execute statement and get the max id correctly for your query

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlOI)){
   header("Location: account.php?success=orderPlaced");
   exit();
 }
```

this way you only need to do 1 connection.  I'm going to assume that you will take the advice of the comments regarding using prepared statements and will.
 -- UPDATE --

Based on your comment below, I will add this:

You are never updating your variables.  Lets just take 1

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
```

this is set once, and never updated so logically every iteration of the loop will insert the same value.  in your form you use the same name for your inputs:

```
 <td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>"></td>
```

But you only get one value - can't remember if it's the first or the last, but a quick google will soon tell you.  If you want to submit multiple values you need to give unique name for use post array syntax on your form  `<input type="text" name="title[]"...`

then when you are doing your insert loop you will be able to access the correct value by saying

`$title = $_POST['title'][$i];`

You need to var_dump some of your variables so that you can see what the data you are sending is, because I'm fairly confident it's not the same as the data you think you are getting

Comment: I added `$conn->query($sqlOI);` inside the for loop and now it inserts the correct amount of rows, but the data of each row is the same.

Comment: well they will be if you're passing the same variables, why do you expect them to be different

Comment: Because they should be different. the `$productID`, `$title` and `$productQty` and the results of input fields that I am passing through. A row with input fields within a HTML table is generated when a new row is inserted into that HTML table. I've edited the question to add this code in

Comment: @NathanJanman - I have edited my answer, please include all the details in your questions in future, the submitting of multiple elements is pretty critical to what you're trying to achieve.  For all we know you want multiple entries of the same values just with individual id's which might later be individually dispatched, cancelled, totalled etc.  We don't have the scope of your project, so you need to be clear

Comment: `I'm going to assume that you will take the advice of the comments regarding using prepared statements and will`. What about you? Will *you* take this advise?

Comment: Always! PDO is my dominatrix and I love her dearly!

Comment: @jameson2012 sprry for the confusion and thanks for your edited answer